# Find which module imported another module

Tags: haxe

I need to find out why some module gets included into compilation.

There is some class that should not be included and I think there are some unused imports or bad architecture that requires unnecessary imports. Is there a way to find which modules import some module, which modules import these modules that include this module, and so on, tracking that down to main class of application?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use `-D dump-dependencies` for this, in which case the compiler will generate two files that can be used to follow the dependency graph in both directions:

- `dump/<target>/.dependants.dump`
- `dump/<target>/.dependencies.dump`

There is also a [handy online tool](http://projects.stroep.nl/haxe/dependencies/) created by [Mark Knol](https://twitter.com/mknol?lang=en) that helps a lot with analyzing these files. To answer the question "what does `Array` depend on?", you can just upload the two files and enter "array" into the search field:

[image]

Conveniently, the results are also clickable.

Answer (score 1):

I've just came up with very simple idea: just delete this file and there will be compilation errors in places where this module is imported.